# How to detect errors in particular records when using the MERGE clause in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure in T-SQL where I receive a table type as input parameter and then I use this table parameter in a MERGE clause.
Thanks to the MERGE clause I'm able to insert or update records in a table in my database.
Sometimes there are issues for several records (because of data quality). When this occurred, is it possible to commit all records that were inserted/updated and in the OUTPUT of the MERGE clause to have the list of records that were in error?
Or is it in a single transaction and then if one error occurred I will have the whole transaction rollbacked?

Comment: Don't use merge. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single transaction, it will rollback everything on error.

Comment: Technically it's a very short answer.

Comment: Ok but is it possible, in the OUTPUT, to have the list of records that failed?

Comment: @DavidGROSPELIER No, all or nothing. You can output the one that were UPDATED/INSERTED/DELETED. But like any other Set based ACID operation, One fails, All fail. So all get Rolled back. You should consider some Data Quality practices to cleanse your data, instead of trial and error.